# Proving exponential distribution given a function

Tags: probability-distributions, independence, exponential-distribution

[image: proveexponential]

I'll admit that I have no idea how to work this one out. I have gotten this far:

I know that I *don't* have to use a differential equation. This is a hint intended to help:
$$\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\frac{f(a)f(h)-f(a)}{h}
=f(a)\frac{f(h)-1}{h}=f(a)\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$$$\text{in the limit }h\to \infty, $$$$=f(a)f'(0)$$$$f'(a)=f(a) c\to\frac{f'(a)}{f(a)}=c$$
How this hint helps is a mystery to me; any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

The hint show that:
$$f'(a)=f(a) f'(0)$$
for any $a \in (0,+\infty)$. In other words with $-\lambda=f'(0)$ you have:
$$\forall x \in (0,+\infty), \, f'(x)=-\lambda f(x) \tag{1}$$
More over $f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)^2$ so:
$$f(0)=1 \tag{2}$$

There is only one differentiable function satisfying $(1)$ and $(2)$ and it is $x \mapsto e^{-\lambda x}$.

Comment: Could you possibly clarify this for me? I still don't follow

Comment: Write:
$$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$$
differentiate with respect to $x$:
$$\frac{d(f(x+y))}{dx}=\frac{d(f(x)f(y))}{dx}$$
$$f'(x+y)=f'(x) f(y)$$
taking $x=0$ and you obtain:
$$f'(y)=f'(0) f(y)$$

Answer (score 1):

The challenge in the question is to avoid using differential equations (or related theory) in the solution.  It turns out **an insightful demonstration can be achieved by assuming much less than is originally supposed and that it requires minimal knowledge of Calculus.**

---

**Let us assume only that $f$ is bounded and bounded away from zero on the interval $(0,1].$**  (This means there exist $u \ge l \gt 0$ and for all $x\in (0,1],$ $l\le f(x) \le u.$)

Since $f(1)\ne 0$ and the exponential function $\lambda\to e^\lambda$ attains all positive real values, there exists a number $\lambda$ for which

$$e^\lambda f(1) = 1.$$

Define the function $\phi:[0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ *via*

$$\phi(x) = e^{\lambda x} f(x).$$

Because the function $x\to e^{\lambda x}$ is bounded and bounded away from zero on $(0,1],$ $\phi$ itself is bounded and bounded away from zero on $(0,1].$  In particular,

$$\phi(1) = e^{\lambda 1} f(1) = 1.$$

**I will show that $\phi$ is constantly $1$.**

The defining relation for $f$ implies that for all $a,b\gt 0,$

$$\phi(a+b) = e^{\lambda(a+b)}f(a+b) = e^{\lambda a} f(a)\, e^{\lambda b} f(b) = \phi(a)\phi(b).$$

In case $b=1,$ this yields

$$\phi(a+1) = \phi(a)\phi(1) = \phi(a)1 = \phi(a).$$

By an easy induction, this result (which shows $\phi$ is *periodic* with period $1$ and therefore the values it attains are precisely the values it attains between $0$ and $1$) demonstrates **$\phi$ is everywhere bounded and bounded away from zero.**

Suppose $a \gt 0$ is any number for which $\phi(a) \ne 1.$  By induction on the natural number $n,$

$$\phi(x + na) = \phi(x)\phi(a)^n.$$

As $n$ grows, the right hand side either diverges (when $\phi(a) \gt 1$) or converges to $0$ (when $\phi(a) \lt 1$) because $\phi(x) \ne 0.$  That contradicts the previous conclusion that $\phi$ is bounded and bounded away frmo zero.  It follows that such a number $a$ cannot exist; that is, **the only value $\phi$ attains is $1$.**

Recalling the definition of $\phi,$ this means $1 = e^{\lambda x}f(x).$  Solving for $f$ gives

$$f(x) = e^{-\lambda x}$$

for all $x \gt 0.$

---

**Part (b) of the question is incorrect.**  However, if in addition you assume $\Pr(X\gt 0) \gt 0,$ then the foregoing analysis applies to $f(x) = \Pr(X \gt x)$ because the axioms of probability imply $f$ is bounded above by $1$ and below by $\Pr(X\gt 0).$ We conclude there is a real number $\lambda$ for which whenever $x\gt 0,$

$$\Pr(X \gt x) = e^{-\lambda x}.$$

Necessarily $\lambda \gt 0$ (for otherwise this function would not decay towards $0$ as $x$ grows).  This is the defining formula for an Exponential$(\lambda)$ distribution, *QED.*